# Best way to replace a character in a string and unreplace it afterwards in C

Tags: c, string, replace, character, quote

I know this question is silly but we are having a program crash due to million of single quotes in the text that is sent to it. The text is indeed again processed by a perl call and returns back. So I wanted to replace single quotes with some character before calling the perl and unreplace it after the perl function returned. what is the best way to do this because if I replace with some characters like # or @ then while replacing them back to quote might cause problem if they contained in original text, what might be the best pattern that can be used as a replacement?

```
 replace("'", "<something>")
```

something can be a string....

Comment: what if the text already has a `#` or `@` in it? now you'll end up with a `'` where one didn't exist before

Comment: Just keeping a copy of the original string might help.

Comment: You have to come up with some escaping scheme. Like, for example, use `#` for a quote, and `##` for `#`. And `####` for `##`. Just  like backslash method.

Comment: @garuda...you could replace with some obscure unique id (a guid perhaps) replace("'", uniqueid)

Comment: @Marc ,yes exactly, that is why I was looking for a better pattern that can be used.....

Comment: @PMF yes we could keep a copy, but we are passing in_msg and the function generates a out_msg which might be different but not entirely kind of like formatted with some lines in between. So copy might not help, the thing is in_msg will be replaced, and out_msg must be unreplaced

Comment: maybe better focus on fixing the crash caused by `'`, or it something really hopless ?

Comment: what does your perl program do with the string?

Answer (score 1):

```
char * bkpstr = strdup( originalString );
for ( char * ptr = originalString; *ptr; ptr++)
{ 
    if ('\'' == *ptr) { *ptr = REPLACEMENT_CHAR; } 
}
```

Then use bkpstr, when you need the original.